# Ansible translation: Installing Apache + Certbot in Ubuntu

Tags: ansible, certbot, apache-httpd

I currently have a doubt for my last line of code to make it work in Ansible, the code is the following:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install apache2 python-letsencrypt-apache

sudo letsencrypt --apache

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot

sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache

sudo certbot --webroot-path /var/www/html -d www.web.tk
```

Now I would like to convert it to Ansible:

```
- apt_repository:
    repo: 'ppa:certbot/certbot'

- apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    update_cache: yes
  with_items:
    - all items above
```

But I have a problem as the line `sudo letsencrypt --apache` requires user interaction and I would like to give it the website and email from Ansible inventory file

Comment: Please add the error logs

Comment: There is no error log, when I do it manually I have no error whatsoever just the translation to Ansible code to execute the raw code with the email and address automatically.

Comment: I suggest to not reinvent the wheel and use an ansible role from galaxy like https://galaxy.ansible.com/030/certbot/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to create the role yourself, you have to use `--agree-tos --noninteractive` to disable user interaction.

See https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html for more details